# Including additional urls in my custom no-index function (Wordpress)

Tags: php, wordpress, function

I have a couple areas on my Wordpress blog that I want to apply the "noindex" tag to. I am doing it this way because the urls are not posts, pages, tags, archives or authors, so it is not as easy as just using something like Yoast.

I have done a little homework and built this code for my functions.php:

```
add_action( 'wp_head', 'custom_add_noindex' );
function custom_add_noindex() {
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] == '/custom_url_1')
echo '<meta name="robots" content="noindex,follow" />';
    }
}
```

However, I am battling to understand how to add multiple urls to this. I need to exclude 3x urls in total, and would prefer not to use use three variations of the same code. Is there a way to include multiple urls in this one function?

Would this perhaps work?

```
add_action( 'wp_head', 'custom_add_noindex' );
function custom_add_noindex() {
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] == '/custom_url_1')
echo '<meta name="robots" content="noindex,follow" />';
elseif($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] == '/custom_url_2')
echo '<meta name="robots" content="noindex,follow" />';
elseif($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] == '/custom_url_3')
echo '<meta name="robots" content="noindex,follow" />';
    }
}
```

Thank you, I would appreciate some advise before I commit it as the site is live and has visitors 24/7, don't particularly want to end up with a white screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
add_action( 'wp_head', 'custom_add_noindex' );
function custom_add_noindex() {
    $urlArray = array('/custom_url_1', '/custom_url_2', '/custom_url_3');

    if(inarray($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], $urlArray) {
        echo '<meta name="robots" content="noindex,follow" />';
    }
}
```

Comment: That looks fantastic, I am sure that will work. Will give it a try in the next few hours, just in a meeting. Thank you so much, I will mark as solved if it works!